# New to c++ and Overloading operators, unsure how to use the function

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

Hi I am rather new to C++, I have just started learning it after learning some Java basics. 
I have pre-existing code were it has overloaded the `>>` operator, however after watching many tutorials and trying to understand the issue, I thought I would ask here.

Rational cpp file:

```
 #include "Rational.h"

#include <iostream>




Rational::Rational (){

}



Rational::Rational (int n, int d) {
    n_ = n;
    d_ = d;
}

/**
 * Creates a rational number equivalent to other
 */
Rational::Rational (const Rational& other) {
    n_ = other.n_;
    d_ = other.d_;
}

/**
 * Makes this equivalent to other
 */
Rational& Rational::operator= (const Rational& other) {
    n_ = other.n_;
    d_ = other.d_;
    return *this;
}

/**
 * Insert r into or extract r from stream
 */

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Rational& r) {
    return out << r.n_ << '/' << r.d_;
}

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Rational& r) {
    int n, d;
    if (in >> n && in.peek() == '/' && in.ignore() && in >> d) {
        r = Rational(n, d);
    }
    return in;
}}
```

Rational.h file:

```
 #ifndef RATIONAL_H_
#define RATIONAL_H_

#include <iostream>
class Rational {
    public:

        Rational ();

        /**
         * Creates a rational number with the given numerator and denominator
         */
        Rational (int n = 0, int d = 1);

        /**
         * Creates a rational number equivalent to other
         */
        Rational (const Rational& other);

        /**
         * Makes this equivalent to other
         */
        Rational& operator= (const Rational& other);

        /**
         * Insert r into or extract r from stream
         */
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Rational& r);
        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, Rational& r);
    private:
    int n_, d_;};

    #endif
```

The function is from a pre-existing class called Rational which takes two `int`s as parameters. Here is the function to overload `>>` :

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Rational& r) {
        int n, d;
        if (in >> n && in.peek() == '/' && in.ignore() && in >> d) {
            r = Rational(n, d);
        }
        return in;
    }
```

And I'm trying to use it like this, after seeing a few tutorials. (The error I am getting is `"Ambiguous overload for operator>>` in `std::cin>>n1` :

```
int main () {
// create a Rational Object.
    Rational n1();
    cin >> n1;
 }
```

Like I said I'm new to this whole overloading operators thing, and figure someone here would be able to point me in the right direction on how to use this function.

Answer (score 10):

Change `Rational n1();` to `Rational n1;`. You've ran into the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). `Rational n1();` does not instantiate a `Rational` object, but declares a **function** named `n1` which returns a `Rational` object.

Comment: Whoa! I would never track this one down if it appear in my code.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric, Sure you can. It's usually as simple as turning on compiler warnings.

Comment: Okay I did that then it says ' :Rational (int, int)'' which I assume it needs ints as parameters? however the parameters are meant to be received from user input.

Comment: @user2333446, I have no clue why it wouldn't contain a default constructor, but I'd just supply two dummy values if you can't change the class.

Comment: @user2333446: As chris says, can you change the class? If not, just provide two dummy values.

Comment: I manually added a constructor that takes no parameters and now I get an error saying "Call to overloaded 'Rational()' is ambiguous".

Comment: @user2333446: It's hard to say without seeing code, but make sure the constructor is of the form `Rational::Rational(){//code here}` if defined outside the class.

Comment: Added the class, should have done that in the first place I just thought the problem was how I was calling the overloaded operator.

Comment: @user2333446: When you have a constructor that takes default arguments, i.e. `Rational (int n = 0, int d = 1);`. That serves as the default constructor since you can call it like `Rational n1;`. Remove the code for `Rational::Rational ()`.

Comment: I removed the Rational::Rational() code now I get the error that I had before ":Rational(int,int)'" like before. 

Then if I put Rational n1(int 1, int 0); I get the "ambiguoes overloaded operator>> in std::cin >> n1" again.

Comment: @user2333446: I ran and compiled your code on two compilers with no problem. [Here is a live example that works](http://ideone.com/v39HUb). Are you sure you didn't forget to delete something in the header? Compare your code with the live example link.

Comment: Hmmm, yea I copy and pasted the code that I had to that site, and it all worked, I don't know maybe it is the IDE I am using or soemthing. :/

Comment: @user2333446: If you post the exact full error message, I might be able to help. For an example like this, it usually is a trivial mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
// create a Rational Object.
    Rational n1();
```

this doesn't create new object but declares a function taking no arguments and returning `Rational`
you probably meant

```
// create a Rational Object.
    Rational n1;
    cin>>n1;
```